# Spyder crashing after installing Keras through Conda

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conda, spyder, win64

I downloaded Anaconda on a PC. I would like to use TensorFlow and Keras. I know I have to use Python 3.6 and TensorFlow 1.0.9 (because of my code).

After installing Anaconda, I open my Anaconda prompt (in admin) and I put these instructions to create a new env:

```
conda create --name deeplearningaz python=3.6 anaconda
activate deeplearningaz
conda install theano
conda install tensorflow
conda install keras
conda update --all
```

I don't have any errors, but a warning about updating Conda version, and a few debug messages.

After that, I try to check if I'm using the correct version of Python, so I type (still in Anaconda prompt) and import keras (to see if it's ok):

```
python
import keras
```

Everything works perfectly fine.
Then I type `quit()` and type `spyder` (to open the Spyder from the env in Python 3.6).
Spyder opens, and if I type anything (import pandas, numpy et read a csv), then it crashes... for no reason (and no error).

After that, still in the Anaconda prompt, I try again to open Spyder and I get an error:

[image: the error after Spyder's crash]

I don't get the problem, I try again and again to uninstall and install anaconda (and checking if my file was really delete). I didn't find...
I check the `print(sys.path)` and it looks like it's ok (but I don't see the env).

**Does anybody have any idea?**

I put here the conda info in the env (before the crash).

[image: conda info]

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Spyder, but based on [this discussion about how they don't really support switching conda envs yet](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4223), it sounds like currently the correct way to get Spyder to use a Conda env is to launch Spyder from outside the env, and then change the Python interpreter (**Tools** > **Preferences** > **Python Interpreter**) to point to the `python` located inside the env you wish to use.

Or if you really don't care about space, simply install a new Spyder instance in the env (`conda install -n deeplearningaz spyder`), and then you should be able to launch within the env without issue.